# How to save multiple form field into database using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have multiple form field generated by jquery  but only save last one record to database

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="form-control" id="quantity[]" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" id="price[]" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Pice" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

The jquery that generate additional form fields is here

```
 $('#priceTable').append(
     "<tr> <td><input class='form-control' id='quantity[1]' name=\"quantity[]\" placeholder='Quantity' type='text'></td><td><input class='form-control' name=\"price[]\"  id='price[1]' +' placeholder='Enter Pice' type='text'></td> </tr>"\
 );
```

The result from on the php page is show below

```
array([quantity] => Array ( [0] => 45 [1] => 60 ) [price] => Array ( [0] => 45000 [1] => 60000 )
```

The loop that suppose to post it to database  but post only one to database

```
 for ($i=0; $i <= $noQuantity; $i++ )
        {
           if(!empty($price)){
               $data = [
                   'price' => $priceRe[$i],
                   'quantity' => $quantity[$i]
               ];
               $price->create($data);
               return redirect('/admin123/category');
           }

         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only creating one because you're redirecting inside the loop, so it creates the first one, and then sends the user to the other page. Try moving it out:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $noQuantity; $i++ )
{
    if(!empty($price)){
        $data = [
            'price' => $priceRe[$i],
            'quantity' => $quantity[$i]
        ];
        $price->create($data);
    }
}
return redirect('/admin123/category');
```

Comment: it works very well but get  **(1/1) ErrorException Undefined offset: 3** after it has been posted to database

Comment: That's a mistake on the loop. You go from 0 to `$noQuantity`, which I assume is the length of the array. So, you're going 1 over the max index. Do this: `for ($i=0; $i <= $noQuantity - 1; $i++ )` or `for ($i=0; $i = $noQuantity - 1; $i++ )`

Comment: Glad I could help! :)